# How can I change chart color according to cell color in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, charts, colors

I have a question about changing the color of a series in a chart to correspond to a cell color in Google Sheets.  I have searched the forum and I can't find a good solution for me.
What I want is for the chart to take color automatically, as on the right side of the screenshot. I want the following 3 different colors.[The screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j49cw.png)

I am expecting to use Google Apps script to achieve this goal.

Comment: I agree that a script is required. Would you please include your script to create the basic chart (and the series).

Comment: Related question: [Automatically Color Series In Chart](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/165597/196152)